# Json set Date Format - Print timestamp and epoch time both

Tags: json, hibernate, date, jackson, datetime-format

I am using objectmapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT).writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(r);

Result: "begin" : 1513644267698,

which returns the values in the object 'r' and the time in epoch format as stored. I now wish to print the time in a readable format, so i did the following change:

DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
return myMapper.setDateFormat(df).enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT).writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(r);

Here i can pass the required dateFormat and print it in my desired format for eg. "EEE MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS (z)".

Result: "begin" : "Tue Feb 20, 2018 09:02:24.941 (UTC)",

My question is - is there any way where i can print both epoch time and the above time format together in the same.

Required Result: "updatedTime" : [1513644267698] Tue Feb 20, 2018 09:02:24.941 (UTC),